# How to use new language features on older JS runtimes with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a TypeScript project that I'm trying to use `flatMap` with. This project will be deployed to Node.js versions as old as v10 (which doesn't support `flatMap`).

I was under the impression that TypeScript will automatically enable support for newer language features even when deploying to older JS runtimes. However I'm getting the following error:

[image: VS Code Error]

```
TypeError: models.flatMap is not a function
```

Which on some level makes sense, I need to ensure that I'm enabling lib compiler support for that new syntax.

However, my `tsconfig.json` file has the following in it:

```
"lib": ["es2019"],
"target": "es2017",
```

What is also strange is the VS Code screenshot error above does not occur when running `tsc`, but does display in the editor, and I do get a runtime error that `flatMap` is not a function.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Side note: if anyone is interesting in looking at the full code base, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/dynamoose/dynamoose/pull/1219).

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn’t polyfill new APIs, only new syntax, which means if you have code that uses flatMap and arrow functions and you compile it to es5, it’ll transpile the arrow syntax, but not flatMap.

Instead, what you have to do is to pass the output through something like Babel, which will include the polyfills for you, so the code works in an es5 environment.